# PHP - Connecting to LDAP with simple bind using sAMAccountName

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to connect to LDAP that uses simple bind through PHP 7.2.

I used LDAP Admin desktop app to check my settings and everything works. The app uses my sAMAccountName in form of `name.surname` and password to log me in. I would like to achieve the same thing through PHP but the only way I managed to get a successful login was below:

```
$ldap_user   = "CN=Name Surname,OU=Users,OU=Sample,DC=sample,DC=othersample";
$ldap_pass   = "myPassword";

$c = ldap_connect("ldap://x.x.x.x", 389);
ldap_set_option($c, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($c, LDAP_ESCAPE_DN, 1);

ldap_bind($c, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);
```

However, my goal is to have `$ldap_user` to be just the `name.surname`, the same way the app uses it.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: are you sure that the ldap-server actually is reachable from the machine in question? I've often seen that network-trafic couldnt get through from the production machine to the LDAP-server.

Comment: And as you are connecting via an LDAP-URI (which is the prefered way) the second parameter is not used at all. So should you actually want to connect to port 389 (which is for LDAP) using the LDAPS-protocol you need to add that port to the LDAp-URI line this: 'ldaps://x.x.x.x:389'

Comment: Thanks for the input! The machine is reachable and I actually managed to get my first successful bind, but it is not what my end product requires. I have rewritten the question to include my latest findings. I'm using the app from ldapadmin.org to connect and browse the LDAP directory in question, so I know which settings work, I just cannot find a way to get them to work in PHP.

Comment: There is not GSS-API involved here. You are doing a simple bind, not even SASL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to do a 3-step approach:

1. Bind to the directory with a known user
2. Search the directory for the entry with sAMAccountName "name.surname" and retrieve the DN for that entry
3. Bind to the directory again now with the just retrieved DN and the user-provided Password.

Have a look for an example at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592

When you are binding to an ActiveDirectory you might also be able to use the sAMAccountName directly when prefixed with the ADs domain like this: `DOMAIN\sAMAccountName`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! `DOMAIN\sAMAccountName` actually worked like charm! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: This would also work for the DN: sAMAccountName@DOMAIN